# Newbie needs help with Wouxun KG UV9D Plus

Tags: weather, squelch

Just got a radio (a Wouxun KG UV9D) from someone that is supposedly "new in box" although I'm really struggling with being able to listen to anything with it. Not sure if it's me or if it's the radio.

Things I have been able to do -- listen to FM radio on it. So, at the very least, I know I can pick up local FM radio.

But, I just want to listen to another transmission, and I figured the NOAA was a good place to start. I entered my local frequency (162.5500) in, and all I hear when I turn on the squelch is static. I think it's receiving because the green button goes on to show it is receiving. I feel like I'm close to something, but am either doing something wrong or my Facebook Marketplace purchase is one that needs to go back to where it came from.

Any tips to figure this out.
I don't know any local HAMs or even where to go to ask for help... so that's sort of a challenge too.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't say where you are. Are you within the typical area for this station? https://www.weather.gov/nwr/sites?site=KEB98 It could also just be the antenna. Many handhelds are quite limited, and bear in mind that the "counterpoise" for the built-in antenna is you basically. But as long as you are in a "narrowband" FM mode it can receive these -- if it can hear them at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you within reasonable range of 162.550MHz? Check the NOAA web site to make sure the station(s) you are interested in are actually near enough to you.
2. Search on the web for "repeaters" in your area and see if you can find one close enough to you so you can listen to the output or monitoring frequency. You should at least hear the repeater announce itself every X minutes (where X is 10 minutes in the US?)
3. If you can, try a different location. Make sure you are holding the radio (because you are essentially acting as the other half of the antenna) and the antenna is pointed up towards the sky. Try a location outside as high as you can get. Use this as an excuse to go hiking!
4. Reset the device using the instructions in the manual (or just search for something like "Wouxun KG UV9D reset"). Today's handhelds (and, indeed, many "base" stations) are more computer than radio, and sometimes a cold restart can fix things.
5. Get an Amateur friend to call on an Amateur frequency some reasonable distance from you. See if you can find a local Amateur club to help with this, perhaps.